# Protect a directory in lighttpd using a php script

Tags: php, authentication, lighttpd

I would like to protect a directory and authenticate users against a mysql database.  I am using lighttpd and haven't been able to find a way of doing so.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use mod_auth, [here](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ModAuth) is the relevant doc page

Since it has no direct access to a database, i would recommend using the 'htdigest' method, and regenerating the file from your database users.

the 'htdigest' format is just: "user:realm:md5(password)", as explained in the page.

Generating a file like this from a php script should be extremely simple.
 pseudo-code:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    // $user['md5pass'] = md5($user['password']);
    $line = sprintf("%s:%s:%s\n", $user['username'], 'protected', $user['md5pass']);
    file_put_contents('htdigest-file', $line, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Also, from the same page, here is a sample lighttpd configuration for mod_auth:

```
auth.backend                   = "htdigest" 
auth.backend.htdigest.userfile = "lighttpd-htdigest.user" 

auth.require = ( "/download/" =>
                 (
                 # method must be either basic or digest
                   "method"  => "digest",
                   "realm"   => "download archiv",
                   "require" => "user=agent007|user=agent008" 
                 ),
                 "/server-info" =>
                 (
                 # limit access to server information
                   "method"  => "digest",
                   "realm"   => "download archiv",
                   "require" => "valid-user" 
                 )

)
```

Comment: Does this mean I need to run the php script every time a username/password combination has been updated to ensure the password file is in sync?  Ideally I would like lighttpd to use a php script as a go between

Comment: I think i get what you mean, (have lighttpd "run" the php script to get the data? i could be mistaken but i don't think it's possible, so that leaves updating the file when users/passwords change.